# Compare data from flat ASCII file against SQL data base. Report non hits

Tags: sql, ascii, flat-file

I'm new to SQL.  Looking for a way to read a flat ASCII file (one field at a time) and then search for non matches within my SQL database.

Comment: Import the file into a staging/temp table and then run the various SQL queries to produce the results you need.

Comment: Reading a file is not a standard sql feature, so it would depend on what database you are using. But generally, first import the flat file into the database.